# How can I add and remove actions in the WooCommerce multiple actions dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm figuring out how I can add / remove actions to the multiple actions dropdown in WooCommerce orders overview:

[image]

I've added some custom order statuses which I want to add here so that I can select some orders and set them all to my custom status 1 for example. I also need to remove some actions here because I don't need them. How can I do this?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the body of the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an action to change order status. Add an action with the index start at "mark_" and then the status name.

For example "mark_shipped".

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_shop_order_bulk_actions', 20 );

    function custom_shop_order_bulk_actions( $actions ) {
        unset( $actions['mark_processing'] ); // remove action

        $actions['mark_new_status'] = __( 'Change status to new status' );

        return $actions;
    }
```

Comment: Look in the file "class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php" method "handle_bulk_actions"